# Memory address for Integer object

Tags: java, memory, integer, stack, heap-memory

I just started to learn Java and I want to ask you a question about Integer objects.

For example we have:

```
 Integer i = new Integer(15);
```

Why I can't see the memory address if I type System.out.println(i)?

I know that if I want to see the memory address for any object I type S.O.P(obj) and i see a memory address like projectname.classname@4141d797 and this is stored in stack, because for reference types, the stack holds a pointer to the object on the heap.

And I see that this is not working for Integer objects. If I type S.O.P(i) I receive 15.

Why in this case the stack doesn't hold the memory address to the object on the heap?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You see this --> `projectname.classname@4141d797` in the console when you print because your custom object doesn't override `toString()`.

Comment: What you see when you do your S.O.P on an object is not necessarily the memory address even when the object does not override toString. See the documentation for toString and hashCode on java.lang.Object: "As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java™ programming language.)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try print an object using the `System.out.println` command what really happens is a call to the `toString` method of that object. All objects implicitly extend the class Object, whose `toString` method returns the output you're familiar with.

However in the case of Integer class the `toString` is overriden and is returning the value of the Integer instead. That's because if you're printing out an Integer it's very likely you just want to learn the number it represents, not the String representation of the object

Answer (score 3):

Because `Integer` overrides the default `Object.toString()` method which gives you the particular output you're thinking about.

It's not even strictly a memory address, even though the current implementation does use the address as the basis for it. However objects can be moved around in memory and that value won't change, so you can't really draw any conclusions from it.

Lastly, you shouldn't care about it. You don't need to worry about where objects are stored with Java.

Answer (score 0):

You only see a memory address for datatypes that do not provide a correct implementation of `toString();`

These types inherit the default behaviour of the `Object` class, which is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--